# CoreData NSFetchedResultsController count not working properly

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have this fetchedResult method:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (__fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return __fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Cards" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Cards" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
         */
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return __fetchedResultsController;
}
```

But when I ask for `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count` it always returns me ONE more item than then it should. The first item is alway this: `"<Cards: 0x83e9c50> (entity: Cards; id: 0x83e9c80 <x-coredata:///Cards/t8C371600-7875-468C-A529-C918F0008C384> ; data: {\n    cardID = nil;\n    favourite = 0;\n    imageData = nil;\n})"` but checking the sqlite via terminal I can see that this item ISN'T THERE.  Any idea on what could it be?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand what is going on. Your code looks good to me. But if you use the cache mechanism, this could be the strange behaviour you have.

To test, try to use `nil` instead of a cache in `NSFetchedResultsController` or delete the cache first and then do the request.

```
+ (void)deleteCacheWithName:(NSString *)name
```

If you pass `nil` all the cashes are deleted.

Let me know if you fix it.

**P.S.** I think that under the hood, cashes are saved and they can live among different app startups. Does anyone know about this?